# Definition of the data types in C (GCC)

Tags: c, types, definition

I know that if I'm looking for the source code of a specific function like `printf` I can see it when I download the glibc and simply open that file.

But where is the source code or definition of the standard data types like `int`, or `double`, etc...

Thanks I'm curious!

Ok, I am not looking for what a function or variable or a data type actually is. I want that file which contains the definition of "int". Is it a structure? But it might be defined somewhere in the GCC... just cant find the file

Comment: `int` and `double` are language keywords.  They are built into the language.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : yes that's it,thats what i also answered

Comment: but where exactly can I find those? It should be open source? Or is it defined in the compiler?

Comment: @int80: Indeed, they will be built into the compiler.

Comment: they just point to some bytes in memory

Comment: @int80: you changed the question ?

Comment: no.u just misunderstood it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only *complex data types* can be defined as structures, primitive data types are *just conventions* of how to lay out bits in memory. The details of those conventions are defined differently in each compiler, across dozens of files handling the different machine code implementations of operations defined on those primitive types.

Indeed there will likely be *hundreds* of files within gcc in which parts of the implementation of an `int` is defined: each operation (cast to char/uint/double/float/etc, plus, times, subtract, divide etc) on each of the dozens of architectures (x86, x86-64, PowerPC) will need to have code generation, optimisations, widths and more defined.

I'd recommend getting a basic understanding of how a compiler works (the standard passes: tokenize, parse, analyse, IL generation, optimisation, code generation) the class I took on it used [The Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) but I've heard others say it's a little dated.

Comment: so if im very lucky i can find that file in the compiler source code... and "COULD" change "int" for instance to "foo"... ?

Comment: wow, I haven't even thought about the front-end parts of the compiler, yeah, so I've just talked about the back end "code-generator", the keyword "int" will be defined somewhere in the tokenizer too.

Comment: so the definition of the data types is in the compiler?Thanks. Thats it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Primitive variables like int, and double don't actually have a 'source code' per se.

Their implementation isn't even very strictly defined by the standard. The hardware that the program runs directly implements the functionality of them, and thus it is the hardware that defines what an int is.

However, if you are curious about how they are implemented, most computers use a [twos-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system for signed integers; and, the [IEEE Floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for implementing doubles and floats.

But none, of this is guaranteed by the C language.

Answer (score 1):

`int` and `double` are `datatypes`,while `printf` is a function

**You cant get source code** of `data types`,they are defined as the data storage format that a variable can store a data to perform a specific operation.

Comment: so its just a accident that int can take numbers and char signs etc...? I learned that data types can be defined with structures... they MUST be defined SOMEWHERE...

Answer (score 1):

From a computers' point of view `int` and `double` are a few bytes in memory representing numbers ,while `printf` is a function which can be called and executed. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type